# Python: create a nested dict from strings of key:value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a dict like this :

```
{"key1:key2[0]:key3[0]": "1234",
 "key1:key2[0]:key4[0]:key5": "4567",
 "key1:key2[1]:key3[0]": "789",
 "key1:key2[1]:key4[1]:key5": "12345"}
```

The keys are a descriptive way of representing the lineage of each final value in the target dict. `:` separates a parent key from its child key, `[]` means the value of the former keys is a list and the index is present between the braces.

Given this, how can I construct a dict like

```
{
   "key1":{
      "key2":[
         {
            "key3":["1234"],
            "key4":[{"key5":"4567"}]
         },
         {
            "key3":["789"],
            "key4":[{"key5":"12345"}]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
result_dict = {}

def populate(target_path, value):
    current_point_in_path = None
    t = result_dict
    target_path = target_path.split(":")
    for i, each_key in enumerate(target_path):
        list_index = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', each_key)
        if len(list_index) > 1:
            raise Exception("not allowed")
        elif len(list_index) == 1:
            index = int(list_index[0])
            key_before = each_key.split(index)[0]
            if not isinstance(result_dict[key_before], list):
                t = t.setdefault(key_before, [])
                if i+1 == len(target_path):
                    # the issue is that this insert won't return a pointer to the current index element like setdefault would do
                    # alternate soultions are wc
                    t.insert(index, value)
                else:
                    t.insert(index, {})

        else:
            if i + 1 == len(target_path):
                t = t.setdefault(each_key, value)
            else:
                t = t.setdefault(each_key, {})
```

I am unable to complete parts of the code here.Maybe I would need a better design with my descriptive language. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: "Maybe I would need a better design with my descriptive language. Any suggestions are welcome."
Where does the data of the source dictionary come from?
Because if you can, I would suggest you to use JSON standard to store this kind of multilevel data structure.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html
With JSON, it is very easy to dump (serialize) and load (deserialize) such structures.

Comment: So what I mean is, if you can change your input data structure to another structure, I would recommend you to use JSON for it.
Then the "decoding" part of the JSON string into a multi-level dictionary is very simple: json.loads(json_string) ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion:

```
import re, itertools
d = {"key1:key2[0]:key3": "1234", "key1:key2[0]:key4": "4567", "key1:key2[1]:key3": "789", "key1:key2[1]:key4": "12345"}
new_d = [(re.findall('\w+', a), b) for a, b in d.items()]
def last_group(d):
  return [{a[-1]:c for a, c in list(b)} for _, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0][1]), key=lambda x:x[0][1])]

def group_data(d):
   return {a:(lambda x:group_data([(c[1:], d) for c, d in x]) if all(len(c) > 3 for c, _ in x) else last_group(x))(list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0][0]), key=lambda x:x[0][0])}

print(group_data(new_d))
```

Output:

```
{'key1': {'key2': [{'key3': '1234', 'key4': '4567'}, {'key3': '789', 'key4': '12345'}]}}
```

Comment: `ValueError: too many values to unpack` on `return {a:(lambda x:group_data([(c[1:], d) for c, d in x]) if all(len(c) > 3 for c, _ in x) else last_group(x))(list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0][0]), key=lambda x:x[0][0])}`

Comment: @void Strange, it works for me in both Python versions. If you are using entirely different input, please post it.

Comment: My mistake. Corrected the input and it works. But the code breaks if I have nested lists, like in the case of the example I've added (edited).

Comment: if you could enhance the answer, I could mark this as accepted, as the itertools solution looks more elegant to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this monster:

```
def populate(result_dict, target_path, value):
    # split path
    target_path = re.findall(r"[^:]+?(?=\[|:|$)|\[\d+?\]", target_path)
    # prepare path
    for i, element in enumerate(target_path):
        if element[0] == "[" and element[-1] == "]":
            element = int(element[1:-1])
        target_path[i] = element
    current = result_dict
    for i, element in enumerate(target_path[:-1]):
        if isinstance(element, str):  # dict index
            if element not in current:  # create new entry
                if isinstance(target_path[i + 1], str):  # next is a dict
                    current[element] = {}
                else:  # next is a list
                    current[element] = []
        elif isinstance(element, int):  # list index
            if element >= len(current):  # create new entry
                current.extend(None for _ in range(element-len(current)+1))
            if current[element] is None:
                if isinstance(target_path[i + 1], str):  # next is a dict
                    current[element] = {}
                else:  # next is a list
                    current[element] = []
        current = current[element]
    if isinstance(target_path[-1], int):
        current.append(value)
    else:
        current[target_path[-1]] = value
```

You can use this code to fill the dict:

```
result_dict = {}
for key, value in {"key1:key2[0]:key3[0]": "1234",
                   "key1:key2[0]:key4[0]:key5": "4567",
                   "key1:key2[1]:key3[0]": "789",
                   "key1:key2[1]:key4[1]:key5": "12345"}.items():
    populate(result_dict, key, value)
print(json.dumps(result_dict, indent=4))
```

prints:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "key2": [
            {
                "key3": [
                    "1234"
                ],
                "key4": [
                    {
                        "key5": "4567"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key3": [
                    "789"
                ],
                "key4": [
                    null,
                    {
                        "key5": "12345"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you please take a look at the updated example? I want to be able to deal with nested lists.

Comment: @void Ok I edited, now it works. The problem was the skip index `key1:key2[1]:key4[0]`, which will be `None` now.